# jQuery targeting this > a where a is not the subject

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have batted together a quick script for changing colours on hover as follows however, I need to be able to target `$(this a).blah()` is it possible to do that?

Using `'#nav ul li ul li a'` targets the entire `ul a` if that makes sense

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // stuff for superfish
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#nav ul li ul li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#4a4a4a");
        $('#nav ul li ul li a').css("color", "#fff");
      }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#404041");
        $('#nav ul li ul li a').css("color", "#ccc");
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find("a").css("color", "#fff");
```

Or a [context part](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
$("a", this).css("color", "#fff");
```

Comment: Ah thats great thank you! I had a feeling I saw the find method before but couldnt remember it :) will note for future thank you! Will accept when it lets

Comment: @JoshBoothe It is rather popular in jQuery. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

try [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
$(this).find('a').css({color:'#fff'})
```

Comment: I think you have to correct it to `$(this).find('a').css({color:"#fff"})`